# Windows 10 Universal - Add multiple code behind files to mainPage

Tags: c#, code-behind, windows-10-universal

I may not be explaining this correctly but I have been looking at Microsoft's ManualCameraControls example application. In that application under MainPage.xaml they have what appear to be multiple code behind file (i.e. MainPage.zoom.xaml.cs).

I am fairly new to Windows 10 Universal, can someone tell me how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "code behind" only describes a concept for humans. The .xaml and .xaml.cs only belong to each other, because they contain partial classes that are compiled into one class. The .xaml.cs files are displayed as a child of their .xaml files in Visual Studio, because there are `DependentUpon` tags in the .csproj. Some example:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="SomeClass.xaml.cs">
    <DependentUpon>SomeClass.xaml</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Page Include="SomeClass.xaml">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </Page>
</ItemGroup>
```

That is how it is achieved in that example, too.

Comment: I can see in the .csprog file where they are added in the <ItemGgroup> so that explains some of it but how would I add a new cs file under MainPage.xaml in the project. Sorry, us old dogs don't get this new fangled stuff

Comment: Just add a normal .cs file to the project. Then unload the project, open it in a text editor and add the DependentUpon tag to the item of the newly created file.